# DB2: Flag the first event and rows that are 60 days after the last flagged event

Tags: sql, db2, logic

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| UserID | VisitDate |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 1/1/21 |
| 001 | 2/7/21 |
| 001 | 3/6/21 |
| 002 | 2/8/21 |
| 002 | 6/3/22 |
| 003 | 4/9/21 |
| 003 | 5/4/21 |

I need to create a logic that would flag the very first visit as a NewVisit per user and then also flag rows if it's more than 60 days since the last "NewVisit".

| UserID | VisitDate | NewVisit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1/1/21 | 1 |
| 001 | 2/7/21 | 0 |
| 001 | 3/6/21 | 1 |
| 002 | 2/8/21 | 1 |
| 002 | 6/3/22 | 1 |
| 003 | 4/9/21 | 1 |
| 003 | 5/4/21 | 0 |

I tried using lag/lead but I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Share the SQL statement that you tried and the problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use the MAX OLAP function instead.

```
WITH MYTAB (UserID, VisitDate) AS
(
VALUES 
  ('001', DATE (TO_DATE ('1/1/21', 'MM/DD/YY')))
, ('001', DATE (TO_DATE ('2/7/21', 'MM/DD/YY')))
, ('001', DATE (TO_DATE ('3/6/21', 'MM/DD/YY')))
, ('002', DATE (TO_DATE ('2/8/21', 'MM/DD/YY')))
, ('002', DATE (TO_DATE ('6/3/22', 'MM/DD/YY')))
, ('003', DATE (TO_DATE ('4/9/21', 'MM/DD/YY')))
, ('003', DATE (TO_DATE ('5/4/21', 'MM/DD/YY')))
)
SELECT 
  UserID
, VisitDate
, CASE 
    WHEN 
      VisitDate = VisitDate_max 
      OR DAYS (VisitDate_max) - DAYS (VisitDate) > 60
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS NewVisit
FROM 
(
SELECT 
  *
, MAX (VisitDate) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID) AS VisitDate_max
FROM MYTAB
)
ORDER BY UserID, VisitDate
```

| USERID | VISITDATE | NEWVISIT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 001 | 2021-02-07 | 0 |
| 001 | 2021-03-06 | 1 |
| 002 | 2021-02-08 | 1 |
| 002 | 2022-06-03 | 1 |
| 003 | 2021-04-09 | 0 |
| 003 | 2021-05-04 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YlOeOKp4)